# SignalR throws 405 error on notify/negotiate request

Tags: .net-core, signalr

I connect to the server with angular like this:

```
    this._hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(location.protocol + '//localhost:5000/notify')
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
  .build();
```

There is no problem with the code or the host. The request works.

But then the library makes an additional call to:

```
http://localhost:5000/notify/negotiate
```

Then I get this error:

> HTTP ERROR 405

The full error in the client is:

> ```
> Failed to load http://localhost:5000/notify/negotiate: Response to
> ```
>
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I don't have cors issues in the site apart from the aforementioned request.

I have this configured in the startup.cs.

```
     app.UseCors(builder =>
              builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyMethod
 ().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin());
```

The code works for all the site.

Why that sudden cors error if the rest of the requests work?

Comment: You have `WithOrigins(...)` and `AllowAnyOrigin()` in the `UseCors` call. Remove the `AllowAnyOrigin()` call and see if that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you to configure directly web.config file of your webapp adding following lines of code (it works on IIS, not sure for IIS Express):

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, X-Requested-With" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I can not find this in .net core

Comment: @JohanVanWambeke the solution I provided was for .NET standard only, not for .NET Core